# How to stop Javascript from changing my text input direction?

Tags: javascript, text, direction

I'm executing the following JavaScript code:

```
document.write('ל');
document.write(' 0 1 2');
```

where the first input is text from a right-to-left language (eg Hebrew or Arabic), and the output is as follows:

> ל 0 1 2

with subsequent writes being written right-to-left, until some input is received which is inherently left-to-right (e.g. Latin characters).

The output still appears left-aligned, and setting the css direction attribute to ltr before the second write doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas where the problem lies?

Comment: document.write makes me cringe. There has to be a better way to do what you are doing than to use document.write.

Comment: Yeah, I just used that to make the point, without having to explain my context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unicode-bidi` and `direction` to style the text:

```
<div style="direction:rtl;">ל<span style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:bidi-override;">0 1 2</span></div>
```

The output:

http://jsfiddle.net/HX4mB/

Here's a link for more information: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction