# How to prevent right-to-left text input?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, frontend, internationalization

How do I prevent, or at least detect, right-to-left text input (such as Arabic or Hebrew) in an input field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479943/how-to-stop-javascript-from-changing-my-text-input-direction

Answer (score 0):

You can try dir attribute property of input tag to specify the text direction.

```
<input type="text" dir="ltr" placeholder="Type here...">
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, you can achieve it using javascript interaction check snippet below

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Type here...">
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
const inputElement = document.getElementById('textInput');
const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

inputElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const text = inputElement.value;
  const rtlRegex = /[\u0600-\u06FF\u0750-\u077F\u0590-\u05FF]/;

  if (rtlRegex.test(text)) {
    resultElement.textContent = 'Right-to-Left text detected.';
  } else {
    resultElement.textContent = 'No Right-to-Left text detected.';
  }
});
</script>
```

Also check no other css rule is affecting your input tag.